# HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Authentication' in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

`HttpContextBase` does not contain a definition for `Authentication` and no extension method `Authentication` accepting a first argument of type `HttpContextBase` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference...

I have tried another way but it displays error above... `HttpContext.SignInAsync`. I'm using VS 2017

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DangNhap(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return View(model);
        }

        //TODO : Do something to authenticate the user
        if (model.Username == "Admin" && model.Password == "admin")
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Username));

            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            //var result =
            //    await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username,
            //        model.Password, true, shouldLockout: false);

            //switch (result)
            //{
            //    case SignInStatus.Success:
            //        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            //    case SignInStatus.Failure:
            //    default:
            //        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            //        return View(model);
            //}

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Errors", "Username và password sai, hãy đăng nhập lại");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: At which line do you have the error?

Comment: await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

Comment: Check if `Microsoft.Owin.Security` & `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` packages installed & referenced properly (try using `System.Web.HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));` instead of using `HttpContext` property in controller action).